# Cannot find search bar in UI tests

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I have a search controller that is created this way:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
searchBar.isAccessibilityElement = true
searchBar.accessibilityIdentifier = "ComplaintSearchBar"
searchBar.accessibilityTraits = .searchField
```

Later the search controller is added to a view controller and its search bar becomes part of the hierarchy. I am trying to test the search bar's existence in a UI test:

```
let searchBar = self.app.searchFields["ComplaintSearchBar"]
XCTAssert(searchBar.waitForExistence(timeout: 2.0))
```

But the test keeps failing, it doesn't find the search bar. I am interested in the search field more than the search bar, but the problem is that in iOS 12 and lower there is no way (expect for a hack, using valueForKey) to get the search field. Any convenient solution?